# Passed to class variable not being updated

Tags: c#

This should sound like a really basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer (even tho I know for sure there are plenty), I guess my Googling skills are bad, or maybe I don't know what to search for.

I have this code:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var service = new Service();

        service.Execute();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private int _foo;

    public void Execute()
    {
        _foo = 1;

        var bar = new Bar(_foo);

        _foo = 2;

        bar.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly int _foo;

    public Bar(int foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public void WriteLine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_foo);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so it prints `2`? (basically the new value after `Bar` has been initialized)

I tried using `ref` but no luck.

Comment: Wrap the int in a reference type.

Comment: @Rotem Hello, thanks for your answer! How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense for a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)

> Value types and reference types are the two main categories of C#
>   types. A variable of a value type contains an instance of the type.
>   This differs from a variable of a reference type, which contains a
>   reference to an instance of the type. By default, on assignment,
>   passing an argument to a method, or returning a method result,
>   variable values are copied. **In the case of value-type variables, the
>   corresponding type instances are copied**.

Normally you would create this as a property and set it accordingly

**Given**

```
public class Bar 
{

     public Bar(int foo) => Foo = foo;

     public int Foo {get;set;}

     public void WriteLine() => Console.WriteLine(Foo);

     ...
```

**Usage**

```
public void Execute()
{

    var bar = new Bar(1);

    // set the property instead
    bar.Foo = 2;

    bar.WriteLine();

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there is no way to pass a variable itself without copying it like I'm trying to achieve in my example?

Comment: @Stephanie not without encasing it in another class